# Why doesn't the block gets called with NSNotificationCenter?

Tags: objective-c

I just came across the `NSNotificationCenter` method `[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserverForName: object: queue: usingBlock:` method and since I'm beginning to be comfortable using blocks I decided to try it out since I results in better code readability.

But for some reason I can't get it to work. For what reason doesn't this work

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserverForName:@"SomeNotificationName"
                                                  object:self
                                                   queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]
                                              usingBlock:^(NSNotification *note) {

                                                  NSLog(@"This doesn't work");
                                                  // ... want to do awesome stuff here...

                                              }];
```

where as this works just fine

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(aMethod)
                                             name:@"SomeNotificationName"
                                           object:nil];
//...
//....

- (void)aMethod {
    NSLog(@"This works");
    // ... doing awesome stuff here...
}
```

**END NOTE**
Thanks, for future reference this is my final solution

```
// declared instance variable id _myObserver;
//...

_myObserver = [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserverForName:@"SomeNotificationName"
                                                                          object:nil
                                                                           queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]
                                                                      usingBlock:^(NSNotification *note) {

                                                                          NSLog(@"It's working! It's working!!");
                                                                          // ... again doing awesome stuff here...

                                                                      }];
```

And then finally, (when I'm done with the object)

```
- (void)dealloc {
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:_myObserver];
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Read the doc more carefully :) In the block version, you have to store the return "token" object, for instance in an ivar.

```
id obj = [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
                  addObserverForName:@"SomeNotificationName"
                              object:self
                               queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]
                          usingBlock:^(NSNotification *note) {
                              NSLog(@"This doesn't work");
                              // ... want to do awesome stuff here...
                          }];
//you need to retain obj somehow (e.g. using ivar)
//otherwise it will get released on its own under ARC
```

Also (as mentioned in the docs too), don't forget to remove the observer when you're done with it. In my case, this usually happens in the `dealloc` method of my window/view controller. In your case it may be at a different place. (Of course, if you want the observer until your app quits, you don't need to do this.)

```
- (void)dealloc {      
  //assuming you stored it in _obj ivar
  [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:_obj];

  //no super dealloc under ARC
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `object` parameter in both methods is the sender of the notification.

In the block based one you are passing `self`, in the selector based one you are passing `nil`. That means the block based observer will listen only to notifications generated by `self`.